# Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.2.2 or higher, and running 'pub get'

Tags: firebase, api, flutter, firebase-authentication

https://github.com/alMohamady/Flutter_chat_room/tree/bd9cb7cff011af8f798e5d8056e1f9442808b477

---

I pasted this project in the Android Studio Fadhar, this error is in the image
[[This requires the 'spread-collections' language feature to be enabled.  Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.2.2 or higher, and running 'pub get'.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so some of the package in the project needs a minimum SDK version to be 2.2.2
so all you have to do is to change it in your project

In the root folder of your  project, open pubspec.yaml, find `sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"` in it and change it to `sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"`. Just change that, run `flutter clean` in the terminal on your project directory and try to run your app.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the root folder of your app, open `pubspec.yaml`, find `sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"` in it and change it to `sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"`. Be careful, it can break other dependencies. Just change that, run `flutter clean` and try to run your app. Watch for errors in debug console.